# DNS redirection between 2 subdomains

Tags: redirect, dns

I have a client with a domain: client.com
I host his project on my server with a custom subdomain: client.mycompany.com
He would like to create a subdomain: project.client.com to redirect permanently their users to client.mycompany.com

Is it possible to create a DNS redirection between project.client.com to client.mycompany.com?

I have tried to manage DNS with a A record to my IP server, it works need to manage my web server configuration.

Is it possible to redirect a subdomain to an other one with DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS does not do redirects - it only resolves domains to IPs.  You'd have to point the DNS to a web server to handle the redirect.  DNS providers that offer redirection do this behind the scenes.

Nginx is nice for this kind of thing.  Bonus if you already use it.
https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Otherwise, any web server (you may be running apache) should be able to do redirects.
Apache examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html